# Getting the ID of button from an onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have sort buttons for each column of a table in my application, and when I click on one of the sort buttons I want the ID of that button to be passed into the function so that the correct column is sorted. In my HTML I simply have a table as such...

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

I then have a few functions that populate the table with all needed rows from the database. For the function that creates the heading row, it will also append a sort button to the end of each cell in that row. I create the sort button through this following method...

```
const createSortBtn = item => {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
    btn.id = item;
    btn.addEventListener("click", sortTable);
    return btn;
}
```

The variable item is the ID I wish to give the button that is being created, the innerHTML is just a down triangle, and then I also add the onclick function. This onclick function goes as so...

```
const sortTable = () => {
    let order, index = this.id;
    if (document.getElementById(index).innerHTML === '&#9660;') order = "ASC";
    else order = "DESC";
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("order", order);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("index", index);
    makeSearch();
}
```

Most of the function is not too relevant to my question except for the this.id part. From what I have been able to find so far this seems to be the primary method of acquiring the ID of an onclick button (even in strict mode if what I believe is true). However when it is called in the function it is undefined.

I had been thinking that perhaps I could change the code that when I add the onclick function to the sort button it would go like so...

```
const createSortBtn = item => {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = '&#9660;';
    btn.id = item;
    btn.addEventListener("click", sortTable(item));
    return btn;
}
```

...but that seems to call the function immediately which is not the behaviour I wish for.

I have seen that jQuery seems to have quite a few methods of doing this but I am hoping to stick to native JavaScript if possible. Thanks for all help.

Comment: `("click", sortTable(item));` -> `("click", () => sortTable(item));`

Comment: @CertainPerformance This question (Getting the ID of button from an onclick function), is absolutely unrelated to "How to pass arguments to addEventListener listener function?"

Comment: @BekimBacaj OP wants: *when I click on one of the sort buttons I want the ID of that button to be passed into the function so that the correct column is sorted*. This will absolutely be accomplished by the linked canonical (or my above comment).

Comment: It's OK, I don't mind if the OP doesn't.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way through the this.id method? I ask more so for those that may wish to know all the different ways this could be done.

Comment: I don't know @James your code is a mess  of unnecessary `cost` and `function` shorthands with very strange approach to a simple problem\solution procedure. 
There was never been a problem with getting the `id` property of the `click` event element.
Especially in a scenario when you are creating the click elements - because that's a case in which you already have the handle to the target element physically and calling that element by its `id` while holding its hand is like...; you know what it's like.